# How to set different application template for 404 page?

Tags: ember.js

Site has traditional template structure elements: header, content, footer. And almost all pages of the site has such structure. But 404-page doesn't have the header.

So my question is: **Is there some clean way to set unique application template for 404-page?**

Of course, I can add {{ partial 'header' }} to the begining of all templates, beside 404-page, but I hope there is right way to do this ...

Thanx

P.S. Sorry for my English

P.S.S. EmberJS v1.9.1

Comment: When you say 404 page are you talking about Ember's built in error route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst not changing the application template name, you can change the content of the application template from route-to-route by observing the `currentPath` property of the application controller and using an `{{#if}}` helper in the application template to hide and show the header.

This is a cleaner approach than changing the application template name because you won't have to rerender any views.

[Here is a working JS Bin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/zaziqiqije/1/).

Comment: It's much better then my option, I'll try